# Value changes of a form is never triggered when dispatching an input event in a unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to test that a value has change on the form when i type on the input.
The project is using Nrwl nx and the test tool is jest.

component :

```
export class InputNumericComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() form: FormGroup;

  @Input() controlName: string; 

  private _changeSubscription: Subscription;

 private get _control(): AbstractControl | null {
    return this.form?.get(this.controlName);
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this._control) {
       return;
    }
    console.log('init called'); // ok
    this._changeSubscription = this._control.valueChanges
      .pipe(tap((newValue) => this._handleChange(newValue)))
      .subscribe();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this._changeSubscription) {
      this._changeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  private _handleChange(value: string): void {
    console.log('_handleChange'); // never called
  }

  public handleBlur(): void {
    console.log('handleBlur'); // can be called by using dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
  }
}
```

testing file :

```
describe('InputNumericComponent', () => {
  let component: InputNumericComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InputNumericComponent>;

  configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [InputNumericComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputNumericComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.controlName = 'numeric';
    component.form = new FormGroup({
      numeric: new FormControl(),
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should update form', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    input.nativeElement.value = '222';
    // i tried both and others like keydown, keypress, etc..
    input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    console.log('form', component.form.get('numeric')?.value); // null
    expect(input.form.get('numeric')).toEqual('222');
  }));
});
```

I don't know why but the input event doesn't trigger the `valueChanges`, if i dispatch a `blur` event the `handleBlur` function is called but i don't know how to trigger the `valueChanges`, i've tried `keydown`, `keypress`.

I've tried to dispatch an input event directly on the input and it works, the `_handleChange` is called but don't know why in the test it doesn't work.

I've tried the other method using `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input')` but it doesn't work too.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ReactiveFormsModule` to you TestBed imports.

Comment: I already tried but it doesn't work too, i hadn't seen that i was using the `change` event in the post but initialy i was using `input` but it doesn't work..

Comment: @JulienMETRAL Can you try adding `ReactiveFormsModule` in TestBed imports?

Comment: It works ! thanks a lot ! You can edit your answer i will accept and mark this as correct